# C++ How to compare set<int> from begin to last element -1

Tags: c++

I have this map:

```
std::map<std::set<int>, float> myMap;
```

and `myMap` is initialized as:

```
{ (7, 9), 0.63 } 
{ (7, 11), 0.66 } 
{ (7, 13), 0.72 }
{ (7, 16), 0.73 }
{ (7, 17), 0.67 } 
{ (9, 13), 0.63 } 
{ (9, 16), 0.65 }
{ (9, 18), 0.61 }
```

i want to compare these set such as, if the set A(i1,i2,...in-1) equal to set B(j1,j2,...jn-1) such that i1=j1, i2=j2,.....in-1=jn-1, then:

I will create new set C(i1,i2,.....in,jn)

so **after the first iteration i will have these sets:**

(7,9,11), (7,9,13), (7,9,16), (7,9,17), (7,11,13), (7,11,16), (7,11,17), (7,13,16),(7, 13,17), (7,16,17)

(9,13,16), (9,13,18), (9,16,18)

and **after the second iteration i will have these sets:**

(7,9,11,13), (7,9,11,16), (7,9,11,17), (7,9,13,16),  (7,9,13,17),  (7,9,16, 17)

(9,13,16,18) ** Stop, no more set!!**

and **after the third iteration i will have these sets:**
(7,9,11,13,16), (7,9,11,13,17), (7,9,13,16,17), (7,9,13,16,17) ** Stop, no more set!!**

**To implement the above example**, i think of using `set_differenc` and `set_union`

**to begin with**, i wrote simple code for comparing two vectors:

```
vector<int> a{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
vector<int> b{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8 };
set<int> dest1;
set<int> diff;
set<int> A(a.begin(), a.begin() + 6);
set<int > B(b.begin(), b.begin()+ 6);
std::set_difference(A.begin(), A.end(), B.begin(), B.end(),
std::inserter(diff, diff.begin()));
if (diff.size()==0)
    {

        std::set_union(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(), std::inserter(dest1, dest1.begin()));


    }
    for (set<int> ::iterator it = dest1.begin(); it != dest1.end(); it++)
    cout << *it << " ";
    cout << endl;
```

I defined `a`,and `b` as vector because i want to compare all elements in both `a`,and `b` **expect the last element**

**my question** how can I do the same code above if  `a`,and `b` are sets not vectors, because  i want to apply this simple code on my example above, and `myMap` in my example above is defined as  `std::map<std::set<int>, float> myMap;`

Comment: You are really asking about the portion of your algorithm that operates on sets, right? And the map is not relevant for this question? I suggest you remove the map from set to float from this question, to make it more focused and clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there's a standard function `std::equal` in `#include <algorithm>`. It should be as easy as:

```
#include <algorithm>

set<int> s1{1, 2, 3, 4};
set<int> s2{1, 2, 3, 5};

bool equal = std::equal(s1.begin(), --(s1.end()), s2.begin());
```